# Offset and Pagination in Redis SET

Tags: redis

I have a Redis SET like this :

```
 Key        Value 
  1            9  
  2            17 
  3            20 
  4            5
```

Can i do Offset for a set in redis ? Or if I want to do pagination in a set in redis ?

Comment: Is `Key` unique? Is `Key` also the pagination's order?

Comment: You do not want to do such things, because a set is an unordered data structure. Use another data structure, like a sorted set.